# how do i keep static deflection in a spring at a minimum upon applying gravity in a mass spring system without altering the response?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, vibration, solidworks, machine-design

i modelled a simple mass spring damper system (with a vertical orientation) with base excitation in solidworks. After applying all necessary parameters, i plotted responses with and without gravity applied. I noticed that the steady state responses were equal but the positions were different which is in line with theory. In the response with gravity applied, the bodies overlapped which is undesirable. How can i prevent the bodies from overlapping while maintaining the same response?
Is the different positioning due to the static deflection of the springs? if so, when i increase the value of "k" the response changes. Or am i also to increase the damping coefficient? How does it work? i need some clarification please

Thanks in advance

added pics for reference

[image: no gravity]

no gravity

[image: with gravity]
with gravity

Comment: a screenshot would help to avoid confusion, but it sounds like you just need a longer spring with the same k.

Comment: that works but is there an option that does not involve taking more space

Comment: the pre-load due to the weight of your object (gravity) will compress the spring, so it will take up the same space in the equilibrium state, won't it? // PS- where's the spring? can't see it in the diagram

Comment: didnt think of it that way. Thanks. After simulating, solidworks doesn't display the spring

Comment: Because this is something I am interested in looking, could you provide references that you've looked at to complete this simulation?

Comment: https://youtu.be/_Z0Qd2WPXpI. The link to the solidworks model is in the description of this video